# JavaFX: Node#isHover doesn't recognize if I'm hovering over it

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a property that recognizes when I'm dragging a line from one node to another node.

However, the other node doesn't seem to recognize when it is being hovered over.

To get an idea, here's an image of the process:
[image]

And below is the code I use to have it perform the action when the mouse is dragged:

```
nfaNode.setOnMouseDragged(event1 -> {
    nfaNode.setDelete(false);
    final Point2D mouseInParent = nfaNode.localToParent(event1.getX(), event1.getY());
    if (event1.isShiftDown()) {
        nfaNode.getArrow().setVisible(true);
        nfaNode.setArrowBounds(nfaNode.getBubble().getCenterX(), nfaNode.getBubble().getCenterY(),
                event1.getX(), event1.getY());
        nfaNodes.stream().filter(n -> n.isHover() && !n.equals(nfaNode)).forEach(n -> System.out.println("Hovering over " + n.getText().getText()));
        return;
    }
    nfaNode.getArrow().setVisible(false);
    nfaNode.setLayoutX(mouseInParent.getX() + dragDelta.getDragDeltaX());
    nfaNode.setLayoutY(mouseInParent.getY() + dragDelta.getDragDeltaY());
});
```

Is there a reason as to why Q_1 won't recognize my mouse over it when I am dragging from Q_0 to Q_1?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`isHover`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#isHover--) will really return false, bacause of the [`MOUSE_ENTERED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_ENTERED) event is not fired to your `Node`s (it is fired only for the `Node` where you started the dragging).

From the doc of `isHover()`:

> Note that current implementation of hover relies on mouse enter and
>   exit events to determine whether this Node is in the hover state;

To understand what is happening I copy here a part of the [`MouseEvent` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html) (emphasis is mine):

> **There are three types of dragging gestures.** They are all initiated by
>   a mouse press event and terminated as a result of a mouse released
>   event, **the source node decides which gesture will take place**.
>
> The simple **press-drag-release gesture is default**. It's best used to
>   allow changing size of a shape, dragging it around and so on. **Whole
>   press-drag-release gesture is delivered to one node.** When mouse button
>   is pressed, the top-most node is picked and all subsequent mouse
>   events are delivered to the same node until the button is released. If
>   a mouse clicked event is generated from these events, it is still
>   delivered to the same node.
>
> **During simple press-drag-release gesture, the other nodes are not
>   involved and don't get any events. If these nodes need to be involved
>   in the gesture, full press-drag-release gesture has to be activated.**
>   This gesture is best used for connecting nodes by "wires", dragging
>   nodes to other nodes etc. This gesture type is more closely described
>   at MouseDragEvent which contains the events delivered to the gesture
>   targets.

So, your "dragging" in my first sentence is the dragging of the first kind in the documentation which is not capable to work with other `Node`s, therefore the mouse entered event is not fired for that `Node`s which is used for the calculation in `isHover` method.

In your case, you need the second type of dragging, therefore you have to implement a dragging mechanism between your nodes. A really good place to start is the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm).

**Here is an SSCCE that implements DnD with `Circle`s (no line drawing)**

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

            List<NFANode> nfaNodes = new LinkedList<>();

            Pane pane = new Pane();
            root.setCenter(pane);

            // On pane click we add circles
            pane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {

                if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
                    // If any of the nodes are in hover, do not add new circle
                    if (nfaNodes.stream().anyMatch(n -> n.getCircle().isHover()))
                        return;

                    // Create and initialize the circle, add it to the pane
                    // Wrap it in a NFANode and add it to the list
                    Circle circle = new Circle();
                    NFANode nfaNode = new NFANode(circle);
                    nfaNodes.add(nfaNode);
                    pane.getChildren().add(circle);

                    circle.setCenterX(event.getX());
                    circle.setCenterY(event.getY());
                    circle.setRadius(20);

                    // Circle started to be dragged
                    circle.setOnDragDetected(ev -> {
                        System.out
                                .println("Drag detected on circle: " + circle.getBoundsInParent());

                        // The content will be linked
                        Dragboard db = circle.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.LINK);
                        // Add the index of the NFANode to the DragBoard
                        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                        content.putString(new Integer(nfaNodes.indexOf(nfaNode)).toString());

                        db.setContent(content);
                    });

                    // A circle is hovered while in a drag
                    circle.setOnDragOver(e -> {
                        // Only accept different nodes than the source
                        if (e.getGestureSource() != circle) {
                            String content = e.getDragboard().getContent(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT).toString();
                            Circle draggedCircle = nfaNodes.get(Integer.parseInt(content)).getCircle();

                            System.out.println("Drag over circle: " + circle.getBoundsInParent());
                            System.out.println("Circle dragged: " + draggedCircle.getBoundsInParent());

                            e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
                        }
                        event.consume();
                    });

                    // Drag finished on a node
                    circle.setOnDragDropped(e -> {
                        String content = e.getDragboard().getContent(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT).toString();
                        Circle draggedCircle = nfaNodes.get(Integer.parseInt(content)).getCircle();

                        System.out.println("Drag completed over circle: " + circle.getBoundsInParent());
                        System.out.println("Circle dragged: " + draggedCircle.getBoundsInParent());

                        e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
                    });
                }
            });

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class NFANode {

        private Circle circle;

        public NFANode(Circle circle) {
            this.circle = circle;
        }

        public Circle getCircle() {
            return circle;
        }

        public void setCircle(Circle circle) {
            this.circle = circle;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and the example output:

```
Drag detected on circle: BoundingBox [minX:73.0, minY:97.0, minZ:0.0, width:40.0, height:40.0, depth:0.0, maxX:113.0, maxY:137.0, maxZ:0.0]
Drag over circle: BoundingBox [minX:275.0, minY:289.0, minZ:0.0, width:40.0, height:40.0, depth:0.0, maxX:315.0, maxY:329.0, maxZ:0.0]
Circle dragged: BoundingBox [minX:73.0, minY:97.0, minZ:0.0, width:40.0, height:40.0, depth:0.0, maxX:113.0, maxY:137.0, maxZ:0.0]
Drag completed over circle: BoundingBox [minX:275.0, minY:289.0, minZ:0.0, width:40.0, height:40.0, depth:0.0, maxX:315.0, maxY:329.0, maxZ:0.0]
Circle dragged: BoundingBox [minX:73.0, minY:97.0, minZ:0.0, width:40.0, height:40.0, depth:0.0, maxX:113.0, maxY:137.0, maxZ:0.0]
```

Comment: Thank you, through this, it seems to recognize the gesture. However, db#setContent(content) seems to not allow me to drag my node past a couple pixels.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but this helped me:
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/javafx/event-javafx/javafx-drag-drop-example/

FxDragDropExample1 has it all explained. I'm not sure if you implemented this event handler as well:

```
sourceFld.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler <MouseEvent>()
{
  public void handle(MouseEvent event)
  {
    sourceFld.startFullDrag();
    writelog("Event on Source: drag detected");
  }
});
```

Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseDragEvent.html for more info.